# Octave 'input' function, run through batch file

Tags: batch-file, octave, export-to-excel

I am using a batch file:

```
@echo off
C:\Octave\Octave-4.4.1\octave.vbs --force-gui --eval batchTest("'%~dp0'")
cmd /c
```

to run an Octave script

```
function [] = batchTest(fPath)

disp(fPath);
cd(fPath);

optionNumber = input('Choose option 1 or 2:  ');

if optionNumber == 1            
    fName = input('Input file description:  ',"s");
    filename = [fName ".xlsx"];
    xls = xlsopen(filename,1);       % <-- THIS DOES NOT WORK, PRODUCES "FILE POINTER PRESERVED MESSAGE"
    xls = oct2xls({"OutputData"},xls,1,"A1");
    xlsclose(xls);
end

if optionNumber == 2            
    filename = "TestFile.xlsx";
    xls = xlsopen(filename,1);           %  <-- THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED
    xls = oct2xls({"OutputData"},xls,1,"A1");
    xlsclose(xls);
end
```

to create an Excel file in the batch file's directory.

Option number 1 produces a "File pointer preserved" warning, and the Excel file is not created. It seems that I can't use any string that was created, in whole or in part, by Octave's 'input' function. Inputting the full filename with ".xlsx" and passing that variable to the 'xlsopen' function does not help.  Option 2 works fine, but I need to produce multiple files, so the "fName" descriptor is important. I've tried adding SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION to the batch file. I've also tried a work-around where I used Option 2, and then added

```
rename("TestFile.xlsx",[fName ".xlsx"])
```

to the Octave script, but this produces an "invalid input" error in the 'rename' function, so it doesn't like the 'input'-created string either. The problem is only with the 'xlsopen' and 'rename' functions; the 'input' function works just fine for choosing the option number.

Either option works when directly executing 'batchTest(pwd)' from the Octave command line. The issue only arises when executing from the batch file. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: "this does not work": well of course it doesn't. You overwrite the `xls` filehandle with an `oct2xls` object. It's no longer the same filehandle.  I'm more surprised the second "works" instead. It would REALLY help if you showed us your output instead of just saying "it doesn't work" though. Does your .bat file pass the intended path correctly? As a string? With the correct file separators? Are you passing a unix filepath? Windows? With valid drive? Just the filename? Does the resulting `filename` point to the intended fail with a valid pathstring? Does the (first) xls object open normally?

Comment: if I had to guess, I'd be guessing that your filename is not what you think it is, and that octave is interpreting backslashes in the path as escape sequences. You should not realy on typing paths manually like that, aim to use `fullfile` instead.

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou, I appreciate the tip on `fullfile`, though I'm only using the pathname to change the current working directory, and so it doesn't appear in the `xlsopen` function, only the filename. My problem seems to arise even before the excel file issue, since when I execute `f1 = "String1";
f2 = input('Input file description:  ',"s"); (::type String2::)
fExt = ".xlsx";
filename = [f1 f2 fExt];
disp(filename)
strncmp(filename,f1,length(f1))`
This appears: .xlsxg1String2. However, the strncmp output is 1, so it only seems to display improperly, not actually **be** in that form.

Comment: @smcmi right, this confirms my suspicions. When you collect f2 via input, you are accidentally attaching a `\r` character to your input, which corresponds to the 'carriage return' character. Your string does not contain what you think it does. type `double(f2)` to see you have an extra character at the end (which presumably will be decimal number 13, the ascii number for the `\r` character). If you use `strtrim` on your strings before concatenating them, it should work (assuming there's no other silly stuff going on).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, you were exactly right in every point you made in your last comment. The `strtrim` function removed the carriage return, and everything is working perfectly now. My sincerest thanks! Can I mark your comment as an accepted answer?

Comment: sure, I'll convert to an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue sounds to be that when you create your string, you are including escaped characters that mess up your filename.

From the discussion in the comments it seems the carriage return character is being included in your string, resulting in a wrong filename.

It is unclear why this is only the case when running from the batch file, but as a workaround, you can ensure that the carriage return is removed by preprocessing your string input with `strtrim` to remove any unwanted whitespace.

Comment: Dear @smcmi, since it is still not clear why the carriage return makes it to the string when running in batch mode but not in the interpreter, I have submitted a bug report: [Bug #60453](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60453). If you don't mind, please do contribute to that discussion too if necessary :)